# Python MYSQL store AES BINARY

Tags: python, mysql, encryption

I have a MYSQL table which I access from python, this table must keep the username, password and email encrypted.

I'm encrypting the name and email using aes crypto. And argon2 for the password.

My table is on a cloud server and was created with direct MYSQL command:

```
CREATE TABLE members(member SMALLINT UNIQUE PRIMARY KEY NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, name BINARY(35) NOT NULL, pseudonym VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL, password BINARY(16) NOT NULL, gender CHAR(1) NOT NULL, birthday DATE NOT NULL, email BINARY(40) NOT NULL);
```

I'm having problems with the size of the encrypted blocks, some of them are of 1 byte and others of 3 bytes or that's what I'm understanding.

This is my python query:

```
member_id = i_member
name = aes_encrypt('Name First second')
pseudonym = 'lala'
gender = 'm'
birthday = '2017-12-12'
email = aes_encrypt('email@email.com')
password = ph.hash("password")

self.cur.execute("INSERT IGNORE INTO members VALUES(%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s,%s)", (member_id, name, pseudonym, password, gender, birthday, email))
self.con.commit()
```

The output error is:

```
[22:34:21] SQLCloudDb.py:155: Warning: (1300, "Invalid utf8 character string: 'C8CCA6'")
  member_id, name, pseudonym, password, gender, birthday, height, weight, email, ))
... Similar to password and email
```

If I go to my cloud SQL I can see the inserted members but seems like they have been trimmed, the columns look odd, maybe because some of these bytes are a CLRL?? The following picture includes more columns than my posted code.
[image]

Every help is appreciated Thanks :)

Comment: Unless tis is a toy project or classwork you need to do serious research or hire a competent security developer. Putting users at risk is a serious issue. I say this because there are several  basic mis-understandings in the concept of this code. The major one is that passwords should not e encrypted, they need to be saved in a non-reversible manor, this is achieved by using a password hashing method to create a password verifier.

Comment: **Do not encrypt passwords**, when the attacker gets the DB he will also get the encryption key. When saving a password verifier just using a hash function is not sufficient and just adding a salt does little to improve the security. Instead  use a function such as `PBKDF2`, `Rfc2898DeriveBytes`, `Argon2`, `password_hash`, `Bcrypt` or similar functions with about a 100ms duration. The point is to make the attacker spend substantial of time finding passwords by brute force.

Comment: Hi, I read before and AES was recommended for this task, I'm confused now. I'm using a 16 char key and a 16 char vector. The encryption key is not stored in the DB either the vector. Thanks

Comment: 1. You can read virtually annything on the Internet. In stead look at [NIST Digital Identity Guidelines](http://nvlpubs.nist.gov/nistpubs/SpecialPublications/NIST.SP.800-63b.pdf)
 and 
[Digital Identity Guidelines](https://pages.nist.gov/800-63-3/).

Comment: AES is the go-to encryption method but encryption is not the solution to every problem and encryption of password verifiers is not a suitable secure solution.

Comment: Using a character string for the IV and encryption key is not secure. If you are using a character string for the encryption it needs to have the encryption key derived format with a function such as PBKFD2 (Password Based Key Derivation). The IV needs to be random IV different for each encryption, just prefix the encrypted data with the IV for use in decryption, it does not need to be secret. 3.All of this is just the surface, security is hard to get right,

Comment: And about the issue about the warning storing the generated bytes in the mysql db? I still have to store the name and email encrypted in a reversible way. Thanks for pointing me to NIST.

Comment: It is only the password that needs a non-invertable function. Usually userIDs are not encrypted but that is a use case decision.

Comment: For more general password information take a look at [Toward Better Password Requirements](http://www.slideshare.net/jim_fenton/toward-better-password-requirements) by Jim Fenton
 @jimfenton

Comment: I am not suggesting that this is The One True Way™ but I would suggest that your life will be much easier if you either use Base64 encoding for storing the encrypted blobs and define your columns as `VARCHAR(n) COLLATE ascii_bin`... or use hex-encoding for the blobs and `VARCHAR(n) COLLATE ascii_general_ci`, remembering that `n` in both cases must be larger than the field sizes to accommodate the encoding's expansion.  Either of these approaches causes your blobs to be reduced to printable characters that will give you visual sanity checks and avoid encoding issues between app and db.

Comment: To be clear, I am not saying that Base64 is a form of encryption. It's a serialization format that's useful for blobs and uses 64 symbols from printable ASCII, suitable for storing the encrypted values from AES in a character column.

Comment: Thanks for the readings. I updated the password to be hashed with argon2. But I still have the warning of the invalid character for the binary string.  Warning: (1300, "Invalid utf8 character string: 'F7ABEF'") when trying to insert into MySQL.